# Why does the search function of my CHM file report "No topics found"?

Tags: chm, flare, madcap

I created a CHM help file using MadCap Flare. When I search for a term that I know is present in my text, the search function always reports "no topics found."

How can I fix the search function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case the problem was fixed by registering `itcc.dll` on the machine where Flare is installed (the machine building the CHM.)

```
C:\> regsvr32 itcc.dll
```

The file is included with MadCap Flare as well as the Microsoft HTML Help Workshop.

I have also found an article indicating that the language setting of the help file can affect the search function.

Comment: 4 years later, let me thank you for posting this. Fixed my problem (with HTML Help Workshop creating a CHM [outside of Flare](https://github.com/Phrogz/docubot)). `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop && regsvr32 itcc.dll`

Comment: @Phrogz and 8 years after that

Answer (score -1):

Here is the [Getting Started Guide](http://www.madcapsoftware.com/assets/FlareGettingStartedGuide.pdf).  Chapter 4 has a section about Search, which might prove useful.